# How do I decode Visual C++ method parameters for mangled decorated names?

Tags: visual-c++

Given the exported names examples below:

```
0x00cf ?GetI@PyIDispatch@@SAPAUIDispatch@@PAU_object@@@Z
0x0119 ?ParseTypeInformation@PythonOleArgHelper@@QAEHPAU_object@@@Z
0x014f ?PyObject_FromSTGMEDIUM@@YAPAVPySTGMEDIUM@@PAUtagSTGMEDIUM@@@Z
```

What are the method **parameters** for methods **GetI**, **ParseTypeInformation**, **PyObject_FromSTGMEDIUM**?

Current workaround is to skip parsing the parameters, but then I have the uninformative gap as shown below :)

```
PyObject_FromSTGMEDIUM(...)
ParseTypeInformation(...)
GetI(...)
```

References:

- http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/gcc/gxxint_15.html#SEC20
- http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html
- http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html
- http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv.html#decor
- http://www.int0x80.gr/papers/name_mangling.pdf

> stdcall has the form of _name@x and fastcall has the form of @name@x

How should the algorithm to decode parameters look like? Example in C# would be awesome.

**Constraints: PInvoke is not available.**

Please give also the parameters for the examples above within the anwser.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Run the undname.exe utility from the Visual Studio command prompt.  Use the Edit + Paste command in the system menu to avoid having to type the name.  Sample output:

```
C:\temp>undname ?GetI@PyIDispatch@@SAPAUIDispatch@@PAU_object@@@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?GetI@PyIDispatch@@SAPAUIDispatch@@PAU_object@@@Z"
is :- "public: static struct IDispatch * __cdecl PyIDispatch::GetI(struct _objec
t *)"
```

Comment: Let's assume undname and Dbghelp.dll are unavailable. I am looking for the actual implementation.

Comment: You'll have to break into a vault somewhere in Redmond.  Only compilers have enough info about an identifier to generate the complete name.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html) is an article explaining the mangling algorithm used by Visual C++.

In your case, I think that the first function will be:

```
static ::IDispatch* PyIDispatch::GetI(::_object*);
```

I don't have access to a Windows machine to test however.

Comment: Can you extend your answer to include the steps taken to find the answer? Thank you!

Comment: I did it by hand following the grammar that I liked to (that appears to be outdated).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`UnDecorateSymbolName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681400%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Unfortunately, no p/invoke declaration available on pinvoke.net yet.

Try something like:

```
[DllImport("Dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint UnDecorateSymbolName(string decorated, StringBuffer undecoratedBuffer, uint undecoratedBufferLength, uint flags);
```

Comment: I am actually looking for the implementation. Using PInvoke until it is not available.